# How would you sculpt/model absimple character like this one?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I do not have much experience with Blender and zero sculpting skill. But i really want to make character like this. Where would you even start? What's the first step?

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Is that all the references you got?:) It’s ok, it looks like the character is symmetrical enough. My advice is to analyze the form.

To give a few examples, the head is just an elongate sphere (not cylinder), the hat is basically a section of that sphere. The eyes are squashed spheres with the eyelid being squashed sphere sections. The teeth are a combination of a cylinder stretched in one axis with a spherical end. The mouth is a cut of irregular contour that sits on the top of the spherical head. You have to learn to obtain those forms from simpler forms. 
[image]
[image]

I think the most important parts are the textures and the rendering.